# polymorphic unique_ptr copy elision

Tags: c++, c++14

I have the following code that works on Clang 5.0 but not on Clang 3.8, with C++14 enabled:

```
class Base {};
class Derived : public Base {};

std::unique_ptr<Base> MakeDerived()
{
    auto derived = std::make_unique<Derived>();
    return derived;
}

int main()
{
    auto base = MakeDerived();
    std::cout << "Type: " << typeid(base).name() << '\n';
}
```

[Live Sample Here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/k71d2ODCHxig0Pgl)

Is the return value technically being move-constructed in this case, due to copy elision? And if so, does that mean `unique_ptr`'s move constructor is designed to support implicit upcasts of user class types? It's hard to tell from the [cppreference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) (#6), unless I'm supposed to assume on that documentation page that template type `U` is distinctly different from type `T` for the class itself.

The one thing that makes it obvious this works is that `unique_ptr` is not copy constructible, and since I don't convert it to an rvalue via `std::move()`, there's no other explanation as to why the code would compile other than copy elision. However because it doesn't work with clang 3.8, which accepts the `-std=c++14` flag, I want to make sure the standard itself guarantees that somewhere (and if so, where) and this is just a compiler bug or lack of support issue in v3.8 of Clang.

Comment: Copy elision would mean no copy is made. Move construction would mean one (move) copy is made.

Comment: Right but one outcome of copy elision has to be move construction I thought, especially since the source and destination variable types are different. Honestly, I don't want to make too many assumptions here, since this is basically one of the things I'm hoping for a clear answer to.

Comment: No, copy elision really means no copy happens. Move construction is a copy. But your intuition isn't that far off: the conditions for copy elision are also used to determine whether an lvalue sich as `derived` can be considered as an `rvalue`.

Comment: @void.pointer BTW, your example program has undefined behavior because a derived object is deleted through a pointer to a base that does not have a `virtual` destructor. This is a consequence of the fact that `unique_ptr` (unlike `shared_ptr`) does not use type erasure to store the deleter, yet the conversion c'tor for `default_delete` does not require a virtual destructor. Arguably a standard defect.

Comment: I agree and I'm aware. But not relevant to the question. My example is contrived.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy elision (before C++17) always requires the elided constructor to be actually accessible, so it cannot be the cause of your code working.

Note, however, that C++ (since C++11) has a rule (12.8/32) which boils down to the following: "when returning an object, then under *certain circumstances,* first try treating the object as an rvalue and only if that fails, treat it as the lvalue it is."

In C++11, these "certain circumstances" were "copy elision is possible," which requires the returned object and the return type to be the same type (modulo cv qualification).

In C++14, these "certain circumstances" were relaxed to "copy elision is possible, or the returned object is a local variable in the function."

So in C++11, the code fails, because `std::unique_ptr<Derived>` (the type of `derived`) is different from `std::unique_ptr<Base>` (the return type), and so `std::move` would have to be used.

In C++14, the code succeeds, because `derived` is a local in the function, and is thus treated as an rvalue first. This makes the constructor template you were referring to applicable:

`std::unique_ptr<T>` can be constructed from an rvalue of type `std::unique_ptr<U>` if `U*` can be converted to `T*`.

Your Clang 3.8 seems to be exhibiting the C++11 behaviour; perhaps it has not (yet/fully) implemented the relaxed aspects of C++14 in that version.

---

(And yes, indeed you're supposed to assume that the "template type" `U` is distinct from the class's template parameter `T`. That's why it was introduced in the first place: the constructor being described by #6 is a constructor *template*).

Comment: One nuance: I am not explicitly restricting language to C++11 in clang 3.8. [Here is another sample](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uOai7E6iO2cQQdoI). Note I'm using C++14 on command line. So is this perhaps a bug in clang 3.8 or something from C++14 not implemented yet? Per one of the other answers, might it be missing the "core issue 1579" changes?

Comment: @void.pointer I know, that's why I made that two distinct statements: "It is C++11 behaviour, *and* it is what your Clang 3.8 does." I would assume the reason to be "this feature not yet implemented in that Clang," but I know nothing about Clang release timeline etc. to draw the conclusion. So I just stuck to the facts.

Comment: I didn't catch those details in the intricacy of your statement. Thanks for emphasizing in your follow up comment.

Answer (score 2):

That `return` invokes `unique_ptr`'s converting move constructor template, `template<class U, class E> unique_ptr(unique_ptr<U, E>&&)`. There's no elision; it depends on an implicit move from `derived` enabled by the resolution of [core issue 1579](https://wg21.link/CWG1579).